# Why is my form control being set to null in this very specific instance?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

In this example, I have a parent form and two child form groups to gather address info. The two child form groups are added by a component. I want to add a button on the parent form, that copies the values from the mailing address input to the physical address input.

This means, I not only need to copy the form values, but also the search control values so that it displays the same. This works perfectly fine most of the time. However, when you click the copy to physical button **while the physical address input is focused** you can see (very briefly) that the search control gets set correctly, but then immediately gets set to null.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Select an autocomplete option from mailing address
2. Focus the physical address input (cursor blinking ready for text)
3. Click the copy to physical button and observe the behavior (namely, the value labelled physical address search value)

Minimal example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/shkuxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Faddress-input%2Faddress-input.component.ts

I can't seem to figure out why this behavior is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't say it was easy to find.

As you click on textarea - autocompleteTrigger, it opens a panel and subscribes for [panelClosingActions](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L356). the one that is bothering us is _getOutsideClickStream.

and then when you click somewhere (on the copy button in your case) it calls [_setValueAndClose](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L693) with null value as an event.

[here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L707)
this._element.nativeElement.value is already updated to what you've set but this._valueOnAttach is empty string. that is why it schedules onChange(null) for the animation end [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L714)

don't think there is a good way to fix that. For example you can schedule a value update after the closing logic is calculated to not to fall into that if condition

```
setTimeout(() => {
 this.physicalAddressInput.setSearchControlValue(
   mailingSearchControlValue
 );
})
```

as you can see [writeValue](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L434) method there is an async hack already, I would say because of simillar reasons as yours

Comment: I'm impressed with your ability to figure out the behavior through the source code and is something I'd like to become better at. If you're willing, could you explain your thought process you went through to narrow down the issue. Did you use a debugger and step through the source code?

Comment: @wtylergibbons I used "performance" tab in chrome devtools to record what exactly is executed during this action. however spending some time in that tab is required if you never used it before. also some good knowledge about the framework and change detection is helpful to throw away things that do not matter. then I've put breakpoints to places that are related and walked through them with a debugger (logpoints are also possible. sometimes issues are not repoduced if debugger is stopping the code)

Comment: but knowing that issue is in autocomplete logic it is probably easier to go through the code and fill all places that seem suspicious with breakpoints and go through them with a debugger

Comment: some tricks as providing noop animations and enablingProdMode could also help to reduce noise in the performance tab

Comment: I appreciate you sharing that. I've never used the performance tab before, I'm interested in checking it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @wtylergibbons that tab is rather designed to easily find what exactly in the code taking a lot of cpu (sometimes gpu) and causing lags. This case is not the best one when anyone'd use performance tab, but it is still possible